# Are MT4 Strategy Tester backtest results panel dates somehow linked with MT4 Graph?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, metatrader5

when I see the backtest results, there is a `Result panel`
( Ref. e.g.: https://quivofx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/result.png )

> [image]

that listed all transactions for the backtest.

**Is there a way to quickly scroll to the relevant portion of the graph?**

For example, say buy on 2017.05.03 10.30 EURUSD 5 Min, I would scroll to that portion by just e.g., double click on the entry?

Currently, it is pretty slow for me to go back and forth to check for result entries by scrolling the Graph manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. double click on trade entry or modification or exit and you will see that picture (of course if you ran the test with visual mode=true)
2. press space bar and type data and time then press enter - you will see that the chart moves to the indicated date

Comment: Visual mode=true seems to be very slow, therefore I always run with skipping (let me know if it can run fast). So I think option 2 applies, is there a way to copy the date and time faster from the entries under result panel? Typing is pretty slow.

Comment: yes, it is slow. the fast way is to use with visual mode at 32x speed

Answer (score 0):

### Another fast & built-in method available:

The fastest jump to an exact **`datetime`** value in the MT4 Graph works via the mouse double-click inside the graph's time scale area, near the lower-left corner, where a small gray triangle is present.

A mouse, positioned there for a while, shows a self-explanatory label <kbd>Double click for editing</kbd>

Next, one may type-in or copy/paste there any `datetime` target as one wishes to move to.

```
2016-12-12 08:00
```

and hit  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

So,
**1)** using mouse-select ( over a legitimate `datetime` value as seen in Strategy Tester results et al )
**2)**  <kbd>Ctrl-INS</kbd>  to copy into a paste buffer
**3)**  <kbd>Alt-TAB</kbd> to get into MetaTrader Terminal 4 Graph, if Results were copied from WebBrowser, not from a Strategy Tester sub-window panel in MT4
**4)** using a mouse-doubleclick activate the `datetime` entry field as explained above
**5)**  <kbd>Shift-INS</kbd>  to paste the paste-buffer content
**6)**  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  & voila, you are there.

Comment: Thanks, but copy the entry seems to copy everything like ticket number etc.  We need additional step of pasting it in notepad, and copy the date time portion, isn't it?

Comment: During the times, when this was used, all the reports were systematically saved, as the Strategy Tester was re-run with additional job from a queue. So copy/paste navigation for visual inspections worked well from saved reports.